# Anynonmous share link - download option not available anymore

Tags: sharepoint-online, share

In sharepoint online, when creating a sharing link for anynomous acccess to a ZIP file, the anonymous user can't download the file anymore. There's no download option available. This worked up until a few weeks ago. I've tried setting read permissions, but whatever I do the anonymous user can only see the webpage and can't download the file.

Answer (score 1):

Suffered exactly the same issue. Looks like MS has changed the guestaccess.aspx template which presents a document viewer with different functionality based on the file type.

For zip files this is a folder viewer with no option to download the zip or files within the zip.

As a work around:

1. go to the sharepoint.com admin center
2. click the "sharing" option
3. disable the "generate shorter urls" under "default link type"
4. get or generate a new guest link to the file which will include guestaccess.aspx?share=xyz
5. replace guestaccess.aspx with download.aspx in the URL

this link should result in an instant download for the user.

ps. some terms might differ from actual values since I translated it from the Dutch interface

Answer (score 0):

I just checked sharing anonymously on One drive as well as the SharePoint sites  and was able to see the Download button

1. Did you try to reproduce the issue in the different site collections?
2. Try toggling the external sharing option , disable the external sharing and re-enable it
3. Does it happens with all the users in your tenant?
4. Try sharing the document in One drive and check

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean there is no download option with Anynonmous link? 
[image]

Try to open the Anynonmous link in other browser and compare the results.

Comment: I edited my question, the issue I'm experiencing pertains to ZIP files.